# How to read LV2 ttl file in Python?

Tags: python, rdf

I have an LV2 plugin and I want to use Python to extract its metadata - plugin name, description, list of control and audio ports and specification of each port.

With LADSPA the instructions were pretty clear, although a bit difficult to implement in Python: I just needed to call ladspa_descriptor() function. Now with LV2 there's a .ttl file, simples to access but more complicated to parse.

Is there any python library that will make this job simple?

Comment: Turtle is a syntax for RDF data. Try [RDFlib](https://github.com/RDFLib).

Comment: Maybe you should look at calling out to something like LILV: http://drobilla.net/software/lilv/ If you want to go with native python, then there are lots of tools to read Turtle, and if you can already call LADSPA functions then LV2 is even easier, once you've parsed the turtle.

Comment: For me it appeared that I would have to understand a lot of more complex stuff to parse the turtle using the rdf libs. LADSPA was more difficult to access, but much simpler to interpret the contents, while LV2 is the opposite. About lilv, I tried it, but I'd like to compile the effects and parse the turtle file without installing it to a common lv2 path. Apparently lilv will only look at default installation paths.

Comment: Can you edit your post to add a sample of the data you want to parse? It could be that you can simply find the things you want using e.g. regular expressions (the `re` module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LV2 documentation generation tools use RDFLib.  It is probably the most popular RDF interface for Python, though does much more than just parse Turtle.  It is a good choice if performance is not an issue, but is unfortunately *really* slow.

If you need to actually instantiate and use plugins, you probably want to use an existing LV2 implementation.  As Steve mentioned, [Lilv](http://drobilla.net/software/lilv) is for this.  It is not limited to any static default location, but will look in all the locations in LV2_PATH.  You can set this environment variable to whatever you want before calling Lilv and it will only look in those locations.  Alternatively, if you want to specifically load just one bundle at a time, there is a function for that: lilv_world_load_bundle().

There are SWIG-based Python bindings included with Lilv, but they stop short of actually allowing you to process data.  However there is a project to wrap Lilv that allows processing of audio using scipy arrays: http://pyslv2.sourceforge.net/ (despite the name they are indeed Lilv bindings and not bindings for its predecessor SLV2)

That said, if you only need to get static information from the Turtle files, involving C libraries is probably more trouble than it is worth.  One of the big advantages of using standard data files is ease of use with existing tools.  To get the number of ports on a plugin, you simply need to count the number of triples that match the pattern (plugin, lv2:port, *).  Here is an example Python script that prints the number of ports of a plugin, given the file to read and the plugin URI as command line arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rdflib
import sys

lv2 = rdflib.Namespace('http://lv2plug.in/ns/lv2core#')

path = sys.argv[1]
plugin = rdflib.URIRef(sys.argv[2])

model = rdflib.ConjunctiveGraph()
model.parse(path, format='n3')

num_ports = 0
for i in model.triples(plugin, lv2.port, None]):
    num_ports += 1

print('%s has %u ports' % (plugin, num_ports))
```

Comment: This helped a lot, but still lilv is monstrously complex. After long time hacking and reading API docs (that's the only thing available apparently), I still can't get a simple information like the number of ports a plugin supports: all I can get is a Swig uint32_t pointer, and now looks like I need deep understanding of swig to read the relevant number...

Comment: Sorry, the swig bindings are a bit immature and not widely used or tested (sounds like swig isn't smart enough to marshal a uint32_t). If you really just need to get static information from the Turtle files in Python, using Lilv is probably not the best solution, at least for now.  I have added an example pure Python solution using rdflib.

Comment: I finally parsed the ttl with rdflib. It feeks like an overkill solution at first, but once I got the idea it's pretty clever. The way you parsed the file is much simpler than the way I did, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get the number of ports each plugin supports:

```
w = lilv.World()
w.load_all()
for p in w.get_all_plugins():
    print p.get_name().as_string(), p.get_num_ports()
```

At least this is all i got while trying to figure this out.